# Separate Frame Buffer and Depth Buffer in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, depth-buffer

In DirectX you are able to have separate render targets and depth buffers, so you can bind a render target and a depth buffer, do some rendering, remove the depth buffer and then do more rendering using the old depth buffer as a texture.

How would you go about this in opengl? From my understanding, you have a framebuffer object that contains both the color buffer(s) and an optional depth buffer. I don't think I can bind several framebuffer objects at the same time, would I have to recreate the framebuffer object every time it changes(probably several times a frame)? How do normal opengl programs do this?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for pbuffers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_buffer

Comment: Or FBOs, the pbuffer of the modern API: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/FBO

Comment: Yea, I am talking about FBO's, I just used the render target terminology when talking about how I used them in DirectX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [Framebuffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) is nothing more than a series of references to images. These can be images in [Textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture) (such as a mipmap layer of a 2D texture) or [Renderbuffers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object) (which can't be used as textures).

There is nothing stopping you from assembling an FBO that uses a texture's image for its color buffer and a texture's image for its [depth buffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Depth_formats). Nor is there anything stopping you from later (so long as you're not rendering to that FBO while doing this) sampling from the texture as a depth texture. The FBO does not suddenly own these images exclusively or something.

In all likelihood, what has happened is that you've misunderstood the difference between an FBO and OpenGL's [Default Framebuffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Default_Framebuffer). The default framebuffer (ie: the window) is unchangeable. You can't take *it's* depth buffer and use it as a texture or something. What you do with an FBO is your own business, but OpenGL won't let you play with its default framebuffer in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind multiple render targets to a single FBO, which should to the trick. Also since OpenGL is a state machine you can change the binding and number of targets anytime it is required.